# Programming MacOS-X and the Linux API - POSIX compatible?

Tags: c, linux, macos

I am learning(just finished) C+Algorithms and am a newbie. I wanted to know if the POSIX Linux API is used on a Mac. Linux has functions like pread pwrite readv writev nftw symlink pipe popen posix_self sigprocmask sigaction (system calls). Does the Mac have the same API?? I heard that OS-X is based on a BSD kernel so i was wondering if i could use code written on Linux on OS-X if i stuck to using only POSIX functions. How similar is the OS-X API to the Linux POSIX/SUSv3 API??

Comment: Note that OSX is certified Unix. Linux is not. BSD's roots are in Unix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The Wikipedia article on POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#Fully_POSIX-compliant) has a section dedicated to compliance.  Short answer: yeah, it's going to have all the POSIX functionality you're likely to come up against.  And it will probably have more (e.g. a lot of BSD apis that might not actually be POSIX)

Comment: So if both linux and mac os x are posix compliant why are they binary incompatible? Shouldn't linux terminal programs be able to run on mac then?

Comment: No.  POSIX is an [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API), but to run the same on both operating systems they must also have the same [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), which Mac and Linux do not.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if you can write code that works on both platforms, the answer is yes. If you're asking if that's easy, the answer is probably no.

POSIX is not a Linux standard, but Linux follows it, as does OSX, BSD, HPUX, Solaris, and even some real time operating systems like QNX (just to name a few).

If you program to a POSIX API as much as possible, porting your code will be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

They're *close*. There are some BSD things you won't find in Linux, and some Linux things you won't find on BSD. You can nearly always restrict yourself to a subset which is compatible with both platforms without much trouble. POSIX APIs which are not portable are often given the `_np` designator. You'll also find some things are not (yet) supported on one platform. There is a safe middle ground in the more established APIs. And this can of course vary by which OS versions you are targeting. Implementations may vary slightly if you wander into less common APIs. My first stop is to check the `man` pages.

Comment: will _BSD_SOURCE work (feature test macro)? isn't that supposed to enable definitions that make your code more BSD-ish??

Comment: For a long time, OS X was "BSD-like". since 10.5+Intel, it's formally UNIX compliant - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_03. My recommendation is to use APIs which are compatible with all systems you target (wherever possible) -- just narrow what you use to that subset. x-plat programs gain a lot more complexity when you deviate and start having to implement these APIs for one system. If I find BSD extensions in the source when building on Linux, I just alter the program to use the APIs available on both. OS X is Darwin, which complicates things further.